# Why in molybdenum disulfide the oxidation state of Mo is IV?

Tags: oxidation-state

On one hand, stoichiometrically, it makes sense that in [$\ce{MoS2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum_disulfide) the $\ce{Mo}$ would have +4 and each sulfur would have -2.

[image: MoS2 lattice]([source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/constructing-primitive-cell-using-information-from-chemicaldata))

However, in reality, every $\ce{Mo}$ atom is bonded to 6 sulfur atoms and every $\ce{S}$ atom is bonded to 3 $\ce{Mo}$ atoms. Why in such a complex configuration is it still correct to assign such oxidation numbers? $\ce{Mo}$ participates in 6 bonds, so how are they translated into an oxidation state of 4?

Comment: In sodium chloride each sodium ion has six nearest chloride neighbours. However, sodium is unambiguously +1 oxidation state. If you were to count every one of the six chloride neighbours as belonging to one sodium atom, you would double-count the chloride ions. In fact, you wouldn't even double-count; you would count each chloride ion six times. Likewise the fact that each Mo has 6 nearest S neighbours doesn't mean anything. It could have 4 or 6 or 8 or 12 (it just happens to have 6) and the oxidation state would not be any different as long as the material has the bulk formula MoS2.

Comment: and whether or not Mo in MoS2 has anywhere near a +4 charge (probably *not* since sulfide is quite polarisable) is another matter altogether. Oxidation states aren't necessarily supposed to accurately reflect charges though, so there's no real problem there.

Comment: @orthocresol But each chloride also has 6 nearest neighbors. So theoretically you could "pair up" every Na and Cl in "donor-acceptor pairs".

Comment: Yes, you could. In the same vein you could pair up every Mo with two S.

Comment: @orthocresol but in NaCl those "pairs" are immediately next to each other, while in MoS2 that is not the case.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Solid NaCl doesn't divide itself up into pairs before reacting. All that is required is for the ratio of Mo to S to be 1:2.

Comment: @orthocresol  yes I see your points now. thanks.

Comment: @orthocresol I think you can digest that into an answer ;)